# SLF4J varargs interprets first string as marker

Tags: java, android, logging, slf4j

When using

```
log.trace("with name {}, duration {}, repetitions {}", name, duration, repetitions);
```

SLF4J complains as follows

> [javac] sourcefile.java:105: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Marker
>   [javac]   log.trace("with name {}, duration {}, repetitions {}",
>   [javac]             ^
>   [javac] Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
>   [javac] 1 error

Using

```
log.trace("with name {}, duration {}, repetitions {}",
      new Object[]{name, duration, repetitions});
```

solves the problem, yet seems kludgey. (Especially since the API allows varargs).

Going by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374166/1587329) seems to say that upgrading to SLF4J 1.7 would solve the problem, yet the [android-slf4j is at 1.6.1](http://www.slf4j.org/android/).

Is there a way to use the varargs constructor in SLF4J for Android? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug in the API.

Varargs are used, but for the Marker methods there are also defined methods with 1, 2 and 3 arguments.

```
log.trace(Marker, Object...)
log.trace(Marker, Object)
log.trace(Marker, Object, Object)
log.trace(Marker, **Object**, Object, Object)
```

However the String APIs, only have varargs and 1 and 2 arg methods.

```
log.trace(String, Object...)
log.trace(String, Object)
log.trace(String, Object, Object)
```

For me Varargs do work with 1, 2, or 4, arguments.

Its only a problem with 3 arguments.

Its fixed in 1.7 by changing the highlighted Object to a String.

Answer (score 1):

Try solving your problem with following sample code:

```
log.trace("with name {0}, duration {1}, repetitions {2}", name, duration, repetitions);
```

Comment: This does not work for me with this code exactly.